# How to get specific data from a list of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have this JSON

```
{
  "doctors": [
    {
      "id": 8,
      "schedules": [
        {
          "id": 8,
          "totime": "11:17",
          "dayId": 2,
          "location": "Somajiguda",
          "fromtime": "10:17",
          "hospitalId": 5,
          "day": "Tuesday",
          "hospital": "Yashoda"
        }
      ],
      "username": "d1",
      "degree": "DA(Anaesthesia)",
      "email": "1@2.com",
      "imagePath": "",
      "department": "Bio-Chemistry",
      "name": "d1",
      "userid": 51,
      "gender": "Male",
      "mobile": "1234567900"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "schedules": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "totime": "12:35",
          "dayId": 2,
          "location": "Somajiguda",
          "fromtime": "11:35",
          "hospitalId": 5,
          "day": "Tuesday",
          "hospital": "Yashoda"
        }
      ],
      "username": "d3",
      "degree": "BDS",
      "email": "d3@d3.com",
      "imagePath": "",
      "department": "Bio-Chemistry",
      "name": "d3",
      "userid": 56,
      "gender": "Male",
      "mobile": "1234567890"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "schedules": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "totime": "12:55",
          "dayId": 1,
          "location": "Somajiguda",
          "fromtime": "11:55",
          "hospitalId": 5,
          "day": "Monday",
          "hospital": "Yashoda"
        }
      ],
      "username": "doctor",
      "degree": "BDS",
      "email": "",
      "imagePath": null,
      "department": "Critical Care",
      "name": "doctor",
      "userid": 4,
      "gender": "Male",
      "mobile": "1234567890"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "schedules": [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "totime": "11:17",
          "dayId": 2,
          "location": "Somajiguda",
          "fromtime": "11:17",
          "hospitalId": 5,
          "day": "Tuesday",
          "hospital": "Yashoda"
        }
      ],
      "username": "donald",
      "degree": "DA(Anaesthesia)",
      "email": "donald@doctor.com",
      "imagePath": "",
      "department": "Bio-Chemistry",
      "name": "donald",
      "userid": 47,
      "gender": "Male",
      "mobile": "1234567989"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "schedules": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "totime": "11:15",
          "dayId": 1,
          "location": "Somajiguda",
          "fromtime": "11:15",
          "hospitalId": 5,
          "day": "Monday",
          "hospital": "Yashoda"
        }
      ],
      "username": "john",
      "degree": "BDS",
      "email": "john@john.com",
      "imagePath": null,
      "department": "Anesthesiology",
      "name": "john",
      "userid": 46,
      "gender": "Male",
      "mobile": "1234567890"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "schedules": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "totime": "13:11",
          "dayId": 2,
          "location": "Somajiguda",
          "fromtime": "12:11",
          "hospitalId": 5,
          "day": "Tuesday",
          "hospital": "Yashoda"
        }
      ],
      "username": "sknayak",
      "degree": "BDS",
      "email": "sknayak@sknayak.com",
      "imagePath": "",
      "department": "Anesthesiology",
      "name": "sknayak",
      "userid": 38,
      "gender": "Male",
      "mobile": "1234567890"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "schedules": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "totime": "16:26",
          "dayId": 6,
          "location": "Somajiguda",
          "fromtime": "15:26",
          "hospitalId": 5,
          "day": "Saturday",
          "hospital": "Yashoda"
        }
      ],
      "username": "drsukant",
      "degree": "BDS",
      "email": "",
      "imagePath": null,
      "department": "Anesthesiology",
      "name": "sukant",
      "userid": 9,
      "gender": "Male",
      "mobile": "1234567890"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this JSON there is a field id which is unique.I am getting this json via an ajax like this

```
var test=$.ajax({  
    type: "GET", 
    url: projectUrl+"getDoctors",  
    dataType:"json",
    jsonp: true,
    async:false 
}).responseText;
console.log(test);
```

As you can see in the JSON there is a field id.For example for id=8 username is d1,id=10,username is d3.I am storing the id in session.So for example if id is 8 then I want only those details(username d1,email 1@2.com.....) whose id is 8.

So how to filter the JSON to a specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for a specific item:

```
self.doctors = ko.observableArray();
self.d3Doctor = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.doctors(), function(obj) {
        return obj.id === 8;
    });
});
```

Now you only have to worry about populating the `doctors` observableArray:

```
$.getJSON(projectUrl+"getDoctors", function(response) {
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(yourViewModel.doctors, response.doctors);
});
```

This allows for the following:

```
<div data-bind="if: d3Doctor()">
    <h3>Doctor with ID 8</h3>
    <p>Name: <span data-bind="text: d3Doctor().name"></span></p>
    <p>E-mail: <span data-bind="text: d3Doctor().email"></span></p>
    <p>Address: <span data-bind="text: d3Doctor().address"></span></p>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,+1. can you please tell me what is d3Doctor ?

Comment: `d3Doctor` is the name of the item with id 8. In your html you can now  do the following: `Doctor with ID 8: <span data-bind="text: d3Doctor().name"></span>`

Comment: Ofcourse, see my edit. `d3Doctor` is the item with id 8, so you can use all the properties of that item.

Comment: You still need the ajax call to populate the list (`doctors` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` to find it, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: projectUrl+"getDoctors",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonp: true,
        async: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.doctors, function(i, v) {
            if (v.id == '8') {
                console.log('found', v.username, v.email);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this?:

```
function findById(data, id){
     for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          if(data[i].id === id) return { username:data[i].username, email:data[i].email};
     }
     // Or, you can use $.grep like this:
     // var foundDoctors = $.grep(data,function(e){return e.id === id;})
     // return foundDoctors.length > 0 && foundDoctors[0] || null;

     // Or, you can use filter() method from Array (IE 9+)
}

findById(jsondata["doctors"], 8);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering +1,I am getting the JSON from ajax,so how to do

Comment: Call the method `findById` _after_ you get the data (in `jsondata`). `findById` will return you an object with `username` and `email` of the related doctor.

Comment: I mean in success part of the ajax should I call?+1 for your help

Comment: either of `success` or `done`. Manoj (the other answer) actually showed the way

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I can answer this.

In my way, I personally prefer to turn all the data into array and itenerate it or manipulate it.

As mention in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332225/how-to-push-2-items-to-an-array/23332793#23332793), we already push the data into this format:

```
doctors.push({id:currPat.id,name:currPat.username});
```

So, now I can use the array `filter` function for `doctors` array:

```
var result = doctors.filter(function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.id === 8;
});

console.log(result); // {id: 8, name:d1}
```

Or you can also use the `.map()` in JQuery, and just make the function to check the `data.id` and return the pair you want.

And if you would fight for a `nano` seconds performance. I would guess my method is better than `.map()`

Comment: Can you answer that using knockout.js